# How do I display text vs an image in my Rails app depending on whethre the content is viewed on a small screen?

Tags: css, image, mobile

I'm using Rails 5.  On a particualar search page, I have this logic

```
<%if current_user && result.user_my_object_time_matches && result.user_my_object_time_matches[0] && result.user_my_object_time_matches[0].matches %>
  Saved
<% else %>
  <%= link_to image_tag('plus-icon.png', :alt => 'Save'), logged_in? ? user_my_object_time_matches_create_path(:id => result.id) : '#', :class => logged_in? ? 'link-save' : 'spawn-dialog', title: 'Save', :remote => logged_in?, :data => {:id => result.id} %>
<% end %>
```

What I would like is on mobile browsers (browsers of less than 450 pixel screen width), instead of displaying the word "Saved", I would like to display a check mark icon, the image of which I have downloaded into my project (app/assets/images/checkmark.png).  How do I display different content based on whether the content is being viewed in a small browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with CSS by putting the "Saved" text in an element, and using media queries.

```css
img { display: none; } /* hide by default */

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  img {
    display: block;
  }
  p {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Saved</p>
<img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
```